# What would be the possible reason for server not send syn/ack pack for specific IP address?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tcpip

we have a server that do not respond to a specific internet IP address.

We have looked into firewalls but no obvious setting showing block the IP.

From wireshark, we found that the server received syn package, but do not send back syn/ack package.

We've googled and tried to disable timestamp, but no sign of recovery.

The problem is not historical, it happens few days ago.

From our current experience we do not know what to do or check next.

So as a newbie, could I kindly ask what should I check and what are the possible reasons.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First debug osi osi layers below transport layer. Can you ping the ip from the server? Is Routing configured properly? Just to be sure: Enable the logging of dropped packages in the windows firewall.

Comment: Have you got a firewall on the server?   What happens if you disable the firewall?

Comment: Is the packet arriving on the correct interface (ignore if you only have 1 network interface)